# Why is NEAR `nft_mint` event not emitted?

Tags: nearprotocol

At https://github.com/NEAR-Edu/near-certification-tools/blob/ba220aa6d13b9d8e1996526c796aec203a2853d3/data-contract/src/contract/mint.rs#L41 I call `self.tokens.internal_mint(token_id, to_account_id, Some(combined_metadata))` which calls `NftMint { owner_id: &token.owner_id, token_ids: &[&token.token_id], memo: None }.emit();`

But when I mint an NFT, I never see the `nft_mint` event in the testnet Explorer.

What am I doing wrong, or how can I step through a debug to narrow down to the general area where something is wrong?

The NFT does successfully get minted, in the sense that my TypeScript `const response = await (contract as NFT).nft_tokens_for_owner({ account_id: accountId });` finds it.

Answer (score 2):

Running the TypeScript integration-tests in https://github.com/near-examples/NFT with worskpaces version 3.2.2 will print the smart contract logs, so the standard contract will emit the events with `emit()`.

As for this contract, you can create an `integration-tests` folder in the project root. Here you can make use of the workspaces library to run a local version of NEAR Blockchain and upload your smart contract code to it, and run the `nft_mint` function as follows:

```
import { Worker, NearAccount, tGas, NEAR, BN } from 'near-workspaces';
import anyTest, { TestFn } from 'ava';
import { mint_more, nft_total_supply } from './utils';

const test = anyTest as TestFn<{
    worker: Worker;
    accounts: Record<string, NearAccount>;
}>;

test.beforeEach(async t => {
    const worker = await Worker.init();
    const root = worker.rootAccount;
    const nft = await root.devDeploy(
        '../data-contract/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/near_certification_tools.wasm',
        {
            initialBalance: NEAR.parse('100 N').toJSON(),
            method: "new",
            args: {
                owner_id: root.accountId,
                metadata: {
                    spec: "nft-1.0.0",
                    name: "Certification Tools",
                    symbol: "CT",
                    icon: null,
                    base_uri: null,
                    reference: null,
                    reference_hash: null,
                },
                options: {
                    can_transfer: true,
                    can_invalidate: true
                }
            }
        },
    );

    const alice = await root.createSubAccount('alice', { initialBalance: NEAR.parse('100 N').toJSON() });

    t.context.worker = worker;
    t.context.accounts = { root, alice, nft };
});

test.afterEach.always(async t => {
    await t.context.worker.tearDown().catch(error => {
        console.log('Failed to tear down the worker:', error);
    });
});


test('Simple mint', async test => {
    const { root, alice, nft } = test.context.accounts;
    await root.call(
        nft, 
        "add_issuer",
        { account_id: root.accountId },
    );
    test.log('Issuer set');
    await root.call(
        nft,
        "nft_mint",
        {
            token_id: "0",
            receiver_account_id: alice.accountId,
            token_metadata: {
                title: "Olympus Mons",
                description: "The tallest mountain in the charted solar system",
                media: null,
                media_hash: null,
                copies: 10000,
                issued_at: null,
                expires_at: null,
                starts_at: null,
                updated_at: null,
                extra: null,
                reference: null,
                reference_hash: null,
            },
            certification_metadata: {
                authority_name: "NASA",
                authority_id: null,
                program: "Mars 2020",
                program_name: null,
                program_link: null,
                program_start_date: null,
                program_end_date: null,
                original_recipient_id: null,
                original_recipient_name: null,
                valid: true,
                memo: null
            }
        },
        { attachedDeposit: '8540000000000000000000' }
    );
    test.pass();
});
```

This generates the following output, whereby `EVENT_LOG` is sent to the logs of contract:

[image]